# I want order by date because i am creating upcoming event list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

## I want to order my upcoming event

like I created 3 events 1 is on 23rd, 2nd in on 21 and 3rd is on 24th then it should arrange the event as 21, 23 and 24

This is the serializers.py

```
class UpcomingEventsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        fields = ('id', 'event_title',
                  'small_description', 'event_location',  'event_date')
```

This is the views.py

```
class UpcomingEventsAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                            mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                            mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UpcomingEventsSerializer
    queryset = Events.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
   
    def get(self, request, id=None):

        if id:
            return self.retrieve(request)

        else:
            return self.list(request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
queryset = Events.objects.order_by('-event_date')
```

Comment: I don't think you need `.all()` at the end. i.e., in this case.